# How do I overlay a div on an empty div containing a background image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the #intro div to appear on the .backgroundimg div. I tried various ways like using z-index, positioning but nothing worked. Please help me with a solution and explain how it works.

Html

```
<div class='backgroundimg'></div>

<div id='#intro'>
      <p>
       random content
      </p>
</div>
```

css

```
.backgroundimg {
  background-image: url("http://s9.postimg.org/7c2rqzb2n/homeback.jpg");
  height: 400px;
  width:100%;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: You should use position absolute

Comment: I tried using position relative on the backgroundimg div and position absolute top:0 on the #intro div but it isn't working @A.Wolff

Comment: @KaranJoisher : See my answer, here I gave "position: relative" to parent div and for intro div (child), I gave "position: absolute".  to center the content, I used display table and table-cell property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want something like this ?? If yes, I will explain it in comment section :)

```css
.backgroundimg {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("http://s9.postimg.org/7c2rqzb2n/homeback.jpg");
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  display: table;
}
#intro {
  positon: absolute;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class='backgroundimg'>

  <div id='intro'>
    <p>
      random content
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly I want, can you explain me how it works? does changing display  to table/tablecell have any drawbacks? @jinu

Comment: If my answer resolved your problem, please mark my answer as accepted. 

well, its all about positioning. You give relative position to parent and absolute position to its child to make the child position in side the parent.

display table and table-cell is used to align the text vertically center. 


watch this video for more info https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O37fp6n-AfE